# SELECT all for a huge table not working in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, indexing, amazon-rds

We have a table consisting of 450,000 rows and 90 columns in total.
When we do a simple Select * from table, we get a GC Overhead issue and the process fails.

The table  size is 140 - 160 MB

```
SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size('mytable'));
```

We have index of a field, but there is no WHERE clause in our query so I am not sure if that would help.

We are trying to query in the batch size of 10K records. It is failing for it. Strangely, if we reduced the batch size from 10K to just 10 (yes 10), it still gives the same error of GC overhead.

Here are the configuration at our Postgresql end (we are using AWS RDS)

```
temp_buffer = 8MB
shared_buffers = 32768 (recommended size is 393216 (25% of our maximum memory which is 1.5TB))
work_mem = 4MB (default engine)
effective_cache_size = 16384 (where as the default seems to be 4GB according to documentation)*
```

What kind of optimization can I do at the Database table level to get this working?

Comment: "*a GC Overhead issue*" is not a Postgres problem it's a problem of your application (Postgres doesn't have a runtime garbage collector).  You can verify the runtime of that statement on the server using `explain analyze`. See http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/SlowQueryQuestions for more details on how to ask a question regarding slow statements. And `shared_buffers = 32768` means you assigned 32 **kilo** byte for shared buffers. That is a **really**, really small buffer. You probably want something like 16GB.

Comment: perhaps use a cursor. that will allow you to treat the large result-set as a series of smaller result-sets.

Comment: add `LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 0` to the end of your select. then add add `LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 1000` instead - this ill be for next thousand rows. It is called pagination.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - for the shared_buffers, that's strange. I will change it to 16GB for now and see the performance.